# Comparing Best Times not always working correctly and not sure why

Tags: string, vb.net, timer

This is for VB.NET 2017. I am creating a program and keeping score with the best time. The timer in the program runs like a stopwatch. I would like at the end to compare the best record from a past game with the current time of a new game. If the new game has a faster time then I would like to replace it on the data file. I can do that just fine but sometimes it will put a slower time ahead of the fastest time. I have tried multiple scenarios and cannot get it consistent. If anyone could help that would be appreciated very much. I have some message boxes so I can see some outcomes. They will be commented out later when it is working properly.

```
 If TotalBalls = 2 And SelectPoison = 2 Then
        tmrTime.Enabled = False
        CurrentScore = lblTime.Text
        MsgBox("You win.")
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '   CurrentScore = lblTime.Text
        MsgBox("Current Time is " & CurrentScore)
        NewScoreCheck = String.Compare(CurrentScore, RecordHighScore)
        MsgBox(NEwScoreCheck)
        'NewScoreCheck will be less than 0 if CurrentScore is less (alphabetically) than RecordhighScore
        'NewScoreCheck will be greater than 0 if RecordHighSchore is greater than CurrentScore

        If NewScoreCheck < 0 Then


            MsgBox(CurrentScore)
            Try
                MsgBox("In the try statement. Writing new time")
                Dim FileWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
                FileWrite = New System.IO.StreamWriter("PoisonHighScore.TXT", False)
                FileWrite.WriteLine(CurrentScore)
                FileWrite.Close()
            Catch
                MsgBox("Saving error")
            End Try

        Else
            MsgBox("Not the fastest time.")

        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("You lose.")


    End If

    strExit = MsgBox("Do you want to play again?", vbYesNo)

    If strExit = vbYes Then
        Application.Restart()
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit 1: I am using some variables as TimeSpan which is why I have the values CurrentScore and RecordHighScore as Strings. When I am using TimeSpan it will not store as an Integer and will return an error. I am looking for a way to compare two times but need to store them in such a way that they can be compared which is why I used the compare string method mentioned above. I understand after looking at the solution below as to why I cannot. My question now becomes how do I store them since it cannot be stored as double, single, or integer?

To make it a little more clear think of two racers who finish with two different times and those times being unpredictable. The fastest time would win and we would write to the text file (which I know how to do) the time of the winner.

P.S. I have also tried the CInt(CurrentScore) < CInt(RecordHighScore) but that just returns an error too. Any help again would be greatly appreciated and thank you for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: What is the format of time? and what values are incorrectly ranked faster?

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat it looks like you're doing some implicit type conversions such as:

`CurrentScore = lblTime.Text`

Presumably CurrentScore is a numeric data type (like an Integer or Double), but you're setting the value equal to a String. To correct those errors, turn [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) on. Looking even deeper, this appears to be your problem because you use the String.Compare method to compare the scores alphabetically. To give you an example, String.Compare returns -1 when you pass `1112` and `121` as your current score and high score respectively, but obviously `121` is quicker than `1112`.

What you need to do is convert all numeric values as numeric data types and then compare them using the appropriate [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators).

Comment: I have to have it as a string because TimeSpan cannot be kept as a integer, single, or double. Is there a certain data type I can keep the data type TimeSpan as which will allow me to compare two different times?

Comment: @Shane You can use the [TimeSpan.Milliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.milliseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan_Milliseconds) Property to get the total milliseconds that your TimeSpan's represents, then compare them

Comment: @Shane - On top of what Mark said, you can also compare TimeSpan objects. Take a look at this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eHgx0e

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Timer` to behave like a stopwatch then why not use a `StopWatch`? If you use a `StopWatch`, you can get the `ElapsedMilliseconds` which returns a long. The `Stop` method only pauses the timer; you need to call the `Reset` method to reset the StopWatch to zero. Call this after you collect the ElapseMilliseconds into a variable.

`NewScoreCheck = String.Compare(CurrentScore, RecordHighScore)` Strings are not compared in the same way numbers are.

```
Dim a As String = "72"
Dim b As String = "100"
If String.Compare(a, b) < 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("a comes first")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("b comes First")
End If
```

Result b comes first!

Using a MsgBox to check values is not a great idea. Visual Studio has all sorts of great debugging tools. Inevidibly you will forget to remove a MsgBox; I have :-). Use Debug.Print which will not be in the release version.

```
 Dim sw As New Stopwatch()

 Private Sub BeginGame()
     sw.Start()
 End Sub

 Private Sub OPCode2()
    Dim TimeInMilliseconds As Long = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
    Dim TotalBalls As Integer = 2
    Dim SelectPoison As Integer = 2
    Dim RecordHighScore As Long
    Dim CurrentScore As Long
    If TotalBalls = 2 And SelectPoison = 2 Then
        sw.Stop()
        CurrentScore = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
        sw.Reset() 'So you can play again and get a new time
            MsgBox("You win.")
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Debug.Print($"Current Time is {CurrentScore}")

         If CurrentScore > RecordHighScore Then
            Try
               Debug.Print("In the try statement. Writing new time")
               Dim FileWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
               FileWrite = New System.IO.StreamWriter("PoisonHighScore.TXT", False)
               FileWrite.WriteLine(CurrentScore.ToString)
               FileWrite.Close()
             Catch
               MsgBox("Saving error")
             End Try

         Else
             MsgBox("Not the fastest time.")
         End If
     Else
        MsgBox("You lose.")
     End If
     Dim strExit As MsgBoxResult
     strExit = MsgBox("Do you want to play again?", vbYesNo)
     If strExit = vbYes Then
        'Not a good way to do this, clear your variables and UI
        Application.Restart()
     End If
End Sub
```